# When using presentViewController:animated:completion how can you pass data to the presented View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

When using the presentViewController:animated:completion method how can you pass data to the presented View Controller?

Comment: I need to pass a string between the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should expose properties in the presented view controller interface and set them from the presenting view controller.

```
PresentedViewController* presented = [PresentedViewController new];
presented.stringProperty = @"Hello world!"

[self presentViewController:presented animated:YES completion:^ {
    presented.anotherStringProperty = @"Hello again, world!"; //Set here if you need to pass the value after presentation.
}];
```